# Подскажите пожалуйста, можно ли вызвать функцию modifData без объявления анонимной функции в аяксе?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
function modifData(data){
 return data+1
}

$.post(
 '/',
 {query: 'test'}, 
 function(data){
  modifData(data)
 },
 'json'
)
```

совсем не могу понять как data заполняется результатом запроса в параметре анонимной функции, можно ли без нее обойтись?

Comment: да, можноооооо.

Comment: да, можноооооо.

Comment: да, можноооооо. а как?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вместо

```
function(data){
    modifData(data)
}
```

Надо просто передать ссылку на обработчик

```
modifData
```

То есть одно заменить на другое

Comment: а как это сделать? если просто указать название функции, то я не знаю как достать параметр data

Comment: все, дошло, спасибо, нужно указывать функцию без ковычек

Comment: Да. Т.к. это будет ссылка на неё.